# Extendable Linq Query

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a complicated query that I use several times in my code. I use it to get all the items or just one item:

```
from item in _db.Tests ... select getItem(item)
from item in _db.Tests ...  where item.Id == id select getItem(item)
```

I'd like not to repeat the common part and only call the "getItem" if I will actually use it.

I tried to create a function like that:

```
from item in _db.Tests ...
```

But the compiler complains because I doesn't a select.

I could also create a :

```
private IQueryable<Test> getTests()
{
    return from item in _db.Tests ... select item;
}
```

and then call it like this:

```
from t in getTests() select getItem(t)
```

But that would probably not make use of the optimizations LINQ is capable of... right?

Can you help me with that?

**EDIT**

I realized my problem is more complex: the dots (...) are actually joins and the getItem function uses information from the joins and does some calculations.

Also, I would like to have one function to get all the items and a different one to get a specific item (I want to hide the queries logic from the rest of the program).

I was thinking of doing this:

```
private IQueryable<Tuple<Table1, Table2, Table3, Table4>> queryItems()
{
    return from t1 in _db.Table1s
           join t2 in _db.Table2s on t1.T2ID equals t2.ID into outerT2 from t2 in outerT2.DefaultIfEmpty()
           join t3 in _db.Table3s on t1.T3ID equals t3.ID into outerT3 from t3 in outerT3.DefaultIfEmpty()
           join t4 in _db.Table4s on t1.T4ID equals t4.ID into outerT4 from t4 in outerT4.DefaultIfEmpty()
           select new Tuple<Table1, Table2, Table3, Table4>(t1, t2, t3, t4);
}

public IEnumerable<Item> GetItems()
{
    return from i in queryItems()
           select getItem(i.Item1, i.Item2, i.Item3, i.Item4);
}

public Item GetItem(int id)
{
    return from i in queryItems()
           where i.Item1.ID equals id
           select getItem(i.Item1, i.Item2, i.Item3, i.Item4);
}
```

I don't want to put getItem in queryItems because it does some calculations, and in the case of GetItem(int id), it would run it for every element (right?).

Is this a good way to do the job? Is there a prettier way? A more efficient way?

Comment: Fluent syntax? Try that.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance It doesn't matter if you use method or query syntax.  Both are capable of doing what he wants.

Comment: @Servy It would be easier.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance It would be easier to use whichever the programmer is more familiar with.  If you're more familiar with method syntax that may well be easier/quicker.  If the OP isn't, then perhaps query syntax would be quicker easier.  What he's doing here isn't influenced in any noticeable way by your choice of which syntax to use.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the same query, and just add a condition if required:

```
var items = from item in _db.Tests ... select getItem(item);

// Restrict as necessary
if (fetchSingle)
    items = items.Where(item => item.Id == id);
```

Splitting off the filter (`Where`) into a separate call will have no disadvantages, as it will send the same query to the server when you actually use the resulting `IQueryable<T>` due to LINQ's deferred execution.

Comment: Note that he might not be able to apply the where after calling `GetItem`, if his projection isn't projecting `Id`.

Comment: @Servy True - may need to do that afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

> But that would probably not make use of the optimizations LINQ is capable of... right?

Incorrect.  It's not until you actually try to iterate the query that the query provider attempts to translate the `IQueryable` into an actual database query and execute it.  When you have something like:

```
var query =  db.SomeTable;
```

you haven't fetched the whole table; you've fetched *nothing*.  If you then have:

```
var query2 = query.Where(item => item.SomeProperty == "someValue");
```

then the query provider will be applying that filter to the query it sends to the database.

The easiest/best way to get a good understanding of what's going on is to look at the `Log` value of your DB context.  It will indicate exactly when you're executing a query, and what the query is.  You can then be sure that you're executing exactly the query that you should be when you should be.